# LSM303CTR 3-wire SPI and I2C - conceptual problem

Tags: sensor, i2c, spi, bus, mems

I'm trying to interface LSM303CTR e-compass from ST-microelectronics with microcontroler. Due to design limitations I have to use 4-wire SPI.

This MEMS device has option to switch beetween 3-wire SPI/I2C by using ChipSelect pin (which I personally think is an absurd).

When CS is low - SPI is active, I2C is <strike>en</strike>disabled and chip is selected
When CS is high - SPI is disabled, but I2C is enable

Here lies the problem. 
It I unselected chip by pulling CS high, I also enable I2C transceiver in MEMS device. But my MEMS sensor is connected to same bus with other devices.
I have other devices on same bus (SD memory, LCD). I don't want to interfere with transmission from SD and LCD.

So here are my questions:

1. How to safely interface 3-wire SPI with 4-wire SPI
2. How mentioned I2C transceiver in MEMS device could interfere with my SPI bus while CS is high-state.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I recomend adding a link to the MEMS-device's datasheet in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will have a circuit like this, where M1 is your 4-wire device and U2 is 3-wire device:

[image]

When accessing 3-wire device, you need to send and receive data on the same pin (MOSI). How to achieve this, depends on your MCU. When 3-wire device is sending data, other devices on the bus are not selected, so there's no issue.

According to the [datasheet of LSM303CTR](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/59/aa/fb/3b/85/9e/4e/0a/DM00089896.pdf/files/DM00089896.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00089896.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A91%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C61%2C474%2Cnull%5D), I2C block can be disabled by software.

> In order to disable the I2C block for the accelerometer, CTRL_REG4_A
>   (I2C_DISABLE) must be written to ‘1’, while for magnetometer
>   CTRL_REG3_M (I2C_DISABLE) must be written to ‘1’.

Comment: Thank you! That fully solves my problem. Solution with disabling MEMS's I2C is great idea. I'm using stm32 so the tri-state operation of MOSI shouldn't be a problem.